# What is it called when a DVD or Blu-Ray fragments titles to obfuscate the disk?

Tags: distribution, copyright

I read [a primer on copy protection schemes](http://www.miraizon.com/support/info_copyprotection.html), but it did not mention the scheme I find most commonly, which is to divide the movie into many fragmentary "titles" and make it difficult for a software to know the correct order of titles, so that when a software player attempts to play the movie, it appears fragmented with scenes out of order. What is this methodology of copy protection called?

Comment: I know the method you’re referring to but not the name. The one thing is I’m not sure the movie itself is divided up or if there’s just a huge number of empty titles and/or chapters that causes problems for ripping software.

Comment: Is any of those methods ever succeeded?

Answer (score 5):

It is called **structure protection**.The video stream is divided into a large number of segments between a few seconds and several minutes in length, which are then linked in a different order in each of the "n" titles, only one of which is the correct order for watching the movie.

Any foolish attempt to copy the DVD will either result in an image which is far too large to be burned (because each of the "n" titles will be extracted as a separate video stream, even though the source material is linked, not duplicated), or the ripper will have to guess which is the correct title to extract and most likely pick one which has scenes out of order.